# get positive integer value in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Might be this is a silly question but I'm not able to do this. Is there any way to get only positive value of integer even if my int value is negative. for example I have an int having -15 but I want to use only 15 so is there any way to do this?

Comment: Check if value is <0 then value =  value*-1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
abs().
```

See [manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/abs.3.html) for details.